# grails database-migration plugin: is jndi support on its way?

Tags: grails, database-migration

I have 1.3.2 installed. My investigations found this in scripts/DbmDiff.groovy:

```
// TODO this will fail with JNDI or encryption codec
buildOtherDatabase = { String otherEnv ->
```

Searching the web lead me to this:

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/commit/ac38a7310fe48ba7b5c4dda4d6e30dd8040dbeb6

which is code for DbmDiff.groovy, but in spite of the same TODO comment, appears to handle jndi.

Does this mean that a 1.3.3 is coming soon with jndi support? If so, then I can work around for a while using a temporary env using urls etc.

Regards, John

Answer (score 0):

I'm  not sure when 1.3.3 will be released since this is the only fix so far. It shouldn't be too soon though. Until then you can copy the current script to your application's `scripts` folder. Then you run `grails dbm-diff` Grails will ask you which of the two scripts to run.

Comment: Is DbmDiff invoked from other diff scripts, such as dbm-gorm-diff? My instinct says yes, but absence of added println statements in console says no.
When running it directly, the new code works when jndi is NOT used! When jndi is used the 'otherEnv', but not 'env' the script stops after it has started and the resulting xml file is empty. If jndi is used for 'env' then I get a NameNotFound excn "Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/productionDb] not bound; 2 bindings: [jdbc/developmentDb,jdbc/productionDb]" The two bindings are defined in Config.groovy. Would it help you if we took this offline?

Comment: Raise a JIRA (at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION ) with notes on how to replicate what you're seeing and I'll take a look. I tested it but not extensively.